# Numpy: Calculate Covariance of large array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, covariance

I have a large numpy array of shape `(32,2048,2048)`, where every `[i,:,:]` is a 2D set of pixels which are samples from a spatially correlated statistical distribution. With `i=32` samples for each pixel.

I now need to calculate the [covariance matrix](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) for everey 2x2 ROI (overlapping) on the 2D image, resulting in a a set of 4x4 covariance matrices with total shape of `(4,4,2047,2047)`.

Looping over all ROIs in a loop is of cause possible and takes about 4 minutes on my maschine:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.normal(1000,10,(32,2048,2048))
shape = arr.shape
result = np.zeros((4,4,shape[1]-1,shape[2]-1))
for i in range(shape[1]-1):
    for j in range(shape[2]-1):
         result[:,:,i,j] = np.cov(arr[:,i:i+2,j:j+2].reshape(32,4), rowvar=False, bias=True)
```

But indexing and looping without using numpy build-ins seems inefficient.

So is there a more elegant / faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From numpy 1.20.0+, there is [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view) that allows you to extract the sliding windows. Then you can perform the covariant calculation:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view
a = sliding_window_view(arr, (2,2), axis=(1,2)).reshape(32,2047,2047,-1)

X = a - a.mean(axis=0)

out = np.einsum('ijlk,ijlm,...->kmjl', X,X,1/32)
```

This took about 20s on my system.

Comment: Thanks! I will need to think a bit about the einstein summation to comprehend that it calculates the covariance. The sliding_window_view es exactly what I was seaching for.